# Why does nature favour the Laplacian?

Tags: differential-geometry, symmetry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, differentiation

The three-dimensional Laplacian can be defined as $$\nabla^2=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}.$$ Expressed in spherical coordinates, it does not have such a nice form. But I could define a *different* operator (let's call it a "Laspherian") which would simply be the following:

$$\bigcirc^2=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \rho^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \phi^2}.$$

This looks nice in spherical coordinates, but if I tried to express the Laspherian in Cartesian coordinates, it would be messier.

Mathematically, both operators seem perfectly valid to me. But there are so many equations in physics that use the Laplacian, yet none that use the Laspherian. So why does nature like Cartesian coordinates so much better?

Or has my understanding of this gone *totally* wrong?

Comment: your laspherian is not dimensionally consistent

Comment: That's true but: the Laplacian wouldn't be dimensionally consistent either except we happen to have given x,y, and z all the same units. We could equally well give the same units to $\rho$, $\theta$, and $\phi$. I think @knzhou's answer of rotational symmetry justifies why, at least in our universe, we only do the former. I've never made that connection before, though!

Comment: You can't give the same units to distance and angle.

Comment: @SamJaques Your original question is good, but the above comment comes off as you being stubborn.  You are asking what is more confusing about a convention where angles and distance have the same units than a system where they have different units?  Come on, man.

Comment: @user1717828 Honestly, it's a little more ambiguous than you think, in a general setting. Suppose I give you a spacetime manifold where one coordinate $x$ lies on an interval $[0, x_0]$ with endpoints identified. Is $x$ "really" an angular variable, or are we just dealing with a torus? In the absence of extra mathematical structure, there is no distinction.

Comment: @user1717828 It is more confusing to try to give angles and radius the same units than different units, but I stand by my stubbornness: Why is it less confusing to give Cartesian dimensions get the same unit than different units? (and why not give the same unit to time as well?) And part of the answer seems to be that if I define a "meter" in one direction, I can take any 1-meter object and physically rotate it into another spatial dimension.

Comment: @SamJaques Another argument in support of your position here is that the exact same units argument could be used to dismiss the d'Alembertian, which is extremely useful in relativity, because space and time have different units.

Comment: "Mathematically, both operators seem perfectly valid to me." Mathematically, it's perfectly valid for gravity to disappear every Tuesday or for the electric force to drop off linearly with distance. Most things that are mathematically valid are not the way the universe works.

Comment: @AmIAStudent If you want to take the steelmanning approach, you can easily assume a dimensional coefficient equal to unity in front of each of the angular differential operators. The point is, as beautifully illustrated in **knzhou**'s answer, these necessary dimensional coefficients cannot remain unity in a rotated coordinate system--and thus, the proposed operator is not rotationally invariant.

Comment: @SamJaques *"Why is it less confusing to give Cartesian dimensions get the same unit than different units?"* Because you can set the axis orientation any way you want and the world is invariant to rotations. *"why not give the same unit to time as well?"* That *is* commonly done.

Comment: Mathematically, your "laspherian" makes no sense. It looks like the laplacian in spherical coordinates but differs from it by fatal flaws.

Comment: @my2cts What fatal flaws--I mean why do you think it doesn't make any mathematical sense? It is a mathematically consistent object, the issue is that it is physically much less useful due to the rotational symmetry of the physical world.

Comment: @Dvij Mankad It does not behave properly under symmetry transformation and is inconsistent dimensionally, as was remarked above. It is a nonsense operator.

Comment: @my2cts It is not invariant under symmetry transformations which happen to be symmetry transformations relevant in our usual space. That is a physical issue--not a mathematical one. The dimensionality can be easily restored via introducing dimensionful coefficients of unit value in a specified coordinate system as I described above. Also, see knzhou's comments. It is a usually useless operator--it is not a non-sensical operator.

Comment: @Dvij Mankad So what _is_ the symmetry of this object? Just to make it less nonsensical.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

Nature appears to be rotationally symmetric, favoring no particular direction. The Laplacian is the only translationally-invariant second-order differential operator obeying this property. Your "Laspherian" instead depends on the choice of polar axis used to define the spherical coordinates, as well as the choice of origin.

Now, at first glance the Laplacian seems to depend on the choice of $x$, $y$, and $z$ axes, but it actually doesn't. To see this, consider switching to a different set of axes, with associated coordinates $x'$, $y'$, and $z'$. If they are related by
$$\mathbf{x} = R \mathbf{x}'$$
where $R$ is a rotation matrix, then the derivative with respect to $\mathbf{x}'$ is, by the chain rule,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}'} = \frac{\partial \mathbf{x}}{\partial \mathbf{x}'} \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}} = R \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}}.$$
The Laplacian in the primed coordinates is 
$$\nabla'^2 = \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}'} \right) \cdot \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}'} \right) = \left(R \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}} \right) \cdot \left(R \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}} \right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}} \cdot (R^T R) \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}} = \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}} \right) \cdot \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}} \right)$$
since $R^T R = I$ for rotation matrices, and hence is equal to the Laplacian in the original Cartesian coordinates.

To make the rotational symmetry more manifest, you could alternatively define the Laplacian of a function $f$ in terms of the deviation of that function $f$ from the *average* value of $f$ on a small sphere centered around each point. That is, the Laplacian measures concavity in a rotationally invariant way. This is derived in an elegant coordinate-free manner [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/345236/a-simple-demonstration-that-the-electrostatic-potential-has-no-extrema-in-free-s/345245#345245).

The Laplacian looks nice in Cartesian coordinates because the coordinate axes are straight and orthogonal, and hence measure volumes straightforwardly: the volume element is $dV = dx dy dz$ without any extra factors. This can be seen from the general expression for the Laplacian,
$$\nabla^2 f = \frac{1}{\sqrt{g}} \partial_i\left(\sqrt{g}\, \partial^i f\right)$$
where $g$ is the determinant of the metric tensor. The Laplacian only takes the simple form $\partial_i \partial^i f$ when $g$ is constant.

---

Given all this, you might still wonder why the Laplacian is so common. It's simply because there are so few ways to write down partial differential equations that are low-order in time derivatives (required by Newton's second law, or at a deeper level, because [Lagrangian mechanics is otherwise pathological](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4102/why-are-there-only-derivatives-to-the-first-order-in-the-lagrangian)), low-order in spatial derivatives, linear, translationally invariant, time invariant, and rotationally symmetric. There are essentially only five possibilities: the heat/diffusion, wave, Laplace, Schrodinger, and Klein-Gordon equations, and all of them involve the Laplacian.

The paucity of options leads one to imagine an "underlying unity" of nature, which Feynman explains [in similar terms](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_12.html):

> Is it possible that this is the clue? That the thing which is common to all the phenomena is the space, the framework into which the physics is put? As long as things are reasonably smooth in space, then the important things that will be involved will be the rates of change of quantities with position in space. That is why we always get an equation with a gradient. The derivatives must appear in the form of a gradient or a divergence; because the laws of physics are independent of direction, they must be expressible in vector form. The equations of electrostatics are the simplest vector equations that one can get which involve only the spatial derivatives of quantities. Any other simple problem—or simplification of a complicated problem—must look like electrostatics. What is common to all our problems is that they involve space and that we have imitated what is actually a complicated phenomenon by a simple differential equation.

At a deeper level, the reason for the linearity and the low-order spatial derivatives is that in both cases, higher-order terms will generically become less important at long distances. This reasoning is radically generalized by the Wilsonian renormalization group, one of the most important tools in physics today. Using it, one can show that even rotational symmetry can emerge from a non-rotationally symmetric underlying space, such as a crystal lattice. One can even use it to argue the uniqueness of entire theories, as done by Feynman [for electromagnetism](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391744/does-feynmans-derivation-of-maxwells-equations-have-a-physical-interpretation/).

Comment: In other words, the Cartesian form of the Laplacian is nice because the Cartesian metric tensor is nice.

Comment: I think it's also probably valid to talk about the structure of spacetime; it is Lorentzian and in local inertial frames it always looks like Minkowski space. So if we were to ignore the time coordinates and just consider the spatial components of spacetime then the structure always possesses Riemann geometry and appears Euclidean in a local inertial frame. Cartesian coordinates are then the most natural way to simply describe Euclidean geometry, which is why the Laplacian appears the way it does. Nature favours the Laplacian because space appears Euclidean in local inertial frames.

Comment: In a way you have less than five, since the wave equation can be seen as using the Laplacian for $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ as with the Klein-Gordon equation. So in essence we have three significantly distinct operators.

Comment: And then even though $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\rho^2}$ is *rotationally* invariant, we still don't use that because it's not also translationally invariant.

It seems like the volume element argument is a special case of the invariance: I could define my own volume element $d\rho d\theta d\phi$. But this is useless because all the physical senses of "volume" seem to  correspond to some physical process that seems to be rotationally invariant (say, the event horizon of a black hole, or the space that a gas occupies).

Comment: @SamJaques Indeed. In all the cases that have come up so far, the extra structure needed can be boiled down to the metric tensor. We work in situations where the metric is translationally and rotationally invariant. (This can be formalized in a coordinate-free manner by considering the algebra of Killing vectors.) Given a metric you can define a preferred notation of volume, a preferred scalar second derivative operator (i.e. the Laplacian), and so on.

Comment: Are you drawing a distinction between the heat/diffusion and Schrödinger equations because the latter contains terms depending on the fields themselves, rather than just their derivatives?  (And similarly for "wave" vs. "Klein-Gordon"?)  Or is there another reason that you're differentiating between cases that have the same differential operators in them?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I assumed it was because the "diffusion coefficient" of the TDSE is imaginary, giving a very different form to the solution.

Comment: The third block-set equation makes explicit use of the notion that an inner product is taken between a space and its dual, but the notation associated with that idea appears halfway through as if out of nowhere. It might be better to include the ${}^T$ in the first two dot products as well.

Comment: yes, please explain where that $^T$ suddenly comes from. Just give us the general public some names we could search for.

Comment: @WillNess Ever heard about a [matrix transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose)?

Comment: I am honestly floored by the foundational insights revealed by this answer, yet in a clear and concise way. I really learned a lot by reading it. I sincerely hope you make it the subject of a lecture if you are in a teaching position and haven't already. Very well done.

Answer (score 30):

This is a question that hunted me for years, so I'll share with you my view about the Laplace equation, which is the most elemental equation you can write with the laplacian.

If you force the Laplacian of some quantity to 0, you are writing a differential equation that says "let's take the average value of the surrounding". It's easier to see in cartesian coordinates:

$$\nabla ^2 u = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x ^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y ^2} $$

If you approximate the partial derivatives by

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x }(x) \approx \frac{f(x + \frac{\Delta x}{2}) - f(x-\frac{\Delta x}{2})}{\Delta x}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2 }(x) 
\approx 
\frac{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x } \left( x+ \frac{\Delta x}{2} \right) -  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x } \left( x - \frac{\Delta x}{2} \right)
}
{
\Delta x}
=
\frac{
f(x + \Delta x) - 2 \cdot f(x) + f(x - \Delta x)
}
{
\Delta x ^2 
}
$$

for simplicity let's take $\Delta x = \Delta y = \delta$, then the Laplace equation 
$$\nabla ^2 u =0 $$ 
becomes:
$$
\nabla ^2 u (x, y)
\approx
\frac{
u(x + \delta, y) - 2 u(x, y) + u(x - \delta, y)
}
{
\delta  ^2 
}
+
\frac{
u(x, y+ \delta) - 2 u(x, y) + u(x, y - \delta)
}
{
\delta  ^2 
}
=
0
$$

so

$$
\frac{
u(x + \delta, y) - 2 u(x, y) + u(x - \delta, y) +
u(x, y+ \delta) - 2 u(x, y) + u(x, y - \delta)
}
{
\delta  ^2 
}
=
0
$$

from which you can solve for $u(x, y)$ to obtain
$$
u(x, y)
=
\frac{
u(x + \delta, y) + u(x - \delta, y) 
+
u(x, y+ \delta)+ u(x, y - \delta)
}
{
4
}
$$

That can be read as: "The function/field/force/etc. at a point takes the average value of the function/field/force/etc. evaluated at either side of that point along each coordinate axis."

[image: Laplace equation function]

Of course this only works for very small $\delta$ for the relevant sizes of the problem at hand, but I think it does a good intuition job.

I think what this tell us about nature is that at first sight and at a local scale, everything is an average. But this may also tell us about how we humans model nature, being our first model always: "take the average value", and maybe later dwelling into more intricate or detailed models.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is that (very nice) figure a scan of a hand sketch, or do you have a software tool that supports such nice work?

Comment: Your nice idea that the potential u(x,y) is the average of it's surroundings is exactly the way a spreadsheet (like Excel) is used to solve the Poisson equation for electrostatic problems that are 2-dimensional like a long metal pipe perpendicular to the spreadsheet.  Each cell is programmed equal to the average of it's surrounding 4 cells.  Fixed numbers (=voltage) are then put into any boundary or interior cells that are held at fixed potentials. The spreadsheet is then iterated until the numbers stop changing at the accuracy you are interested in.

Comment: @dmckee thank you for the compliment! I wish it was a software tool but it's my hand. Graphing software draws very nice rendered 3d graphics but I have yet to find one that draws in a more organic way. If you know some that does please recommend!

Comment: I've been experimenting with a Wacom tablet from time to time. But I cheaped out and bought the USD200 one instead of the USD1000 one that is also a high-resolution display. And the result is that I'm having to do a lot of art-school style exercises again to learn to draw on one surface while looking at another and in the mean time I'm just not able to do some of the more sophisticated things I would like to do. But the pressure sensitivity is *very* nice. If you have the funds the pro version might be a better investment.

Comment: The numerical technique @GaryGodfrey mentioned is an example of a *relaxation method*. You can learn more about it from Per Brinch Hansen's report on "Numerical Solution of Laplace's Equation" (https://surface.syr.edu/eecs_techreports/168/), and from many other places too.

Comment: "If you force the Laplacian of some quantity to 0, you are writing a differential equation that says "let's take the average value of the surrounding"." If this were true, the quantity could never have a maximum or minimum value. The analysis you've shown only derives the difference approximations for the Laplacian, without proving your assertion about the averages.

Comment: @D.Halsey that's the "Maximum Value Principle", a theorem which states that the values of a harmonic function (i.e. solution of Laplace's equation) in a bounded domain are bounded by the maximum and minimum values it takes on the boundary.

Comment: @ fredwhileshavin But your assertion about the average value would prevent the boundary from having maximum & minimum values. It's really just a finite-difference approximation.

Comment: @D. Halsey these are properties of the solutions of Laplace's equation. For the boundaries one of the points for the average lies outside the domain and breaks the "average at either side of the point".

Comment: @GaryGodfrey That is not unique to a spreadsheet. Most finite element methods are done on rectangular grids, but the computation is done in a faster programming language like C or Fortran. It's just a function of how you discretize your space.

Answer (score 24):

For me as a mathematician, the reason why Laplacians (yes, there is a plethora of notions of Laplacians) are ubiquitous in physics is *not any symmetry of space*. Laplacians also appear naturally when we discuss physical field theories on geometries other than Euclidean space.

I would say, the importance of Laplacians is due to the following reasons:

(i) the potential energy of many physical systems can be modeled (up to errors of third order) by the Dirichlet energy $E(u)$ of a function $u$ that describes the state of the system.

(ii) critical points of $E$, that is functions $u$ with $DE(u) = 0$, correspond to static solutions and

(iii) the Laplacian is essentially the $L^2$-gradient of the Dirichlet energy.

To make the last statement precise, let $(M,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold with volume density $\mathrm{vol}$. As an example, you may think of $M \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ being a bounded domain (with sufficiently smooth boundary) and of $\mathrm{vol}$ as the standard Euclidean way of integration. Important: *The domain is allowed to be nonsymmetric.*

Then the Dirichlet energy of a (sufficiently differentiable) function $u \colon M \to \mathbb{R}$ is given by

$$E(u) = \frac{1}{2}\int_M \langle \mathrm{grad} (u), \mathrm{grad} (u)\rangle \, \mathrm{vol}.$$

Let $v \colon M \to \mathbb{R}$ be a further  (sufficiently differentiable) function. Then the derivative of $E$ in direction of $v$ is given by

$$DE(u)\,v = \int_M \langle \mathrm{grad}(u), \mathrm{grad}(v) \rangle \, \mathrm{vol}.$$

Integration by parts leads to

$$\begin{aligned}DE(u)\,v 
&= \int_{\partial M} \langle \mathrm{grad}(u), N\rangle \, v  \, \mathrm{vol}_{\partial M}- \int_M \langle \mathrm{div} (\mathrm{grad}(u)), v \rangle \, \mathrm{vol}
\\
&= \int_{\partial M} \langle \mathrm{grad}(u), N \rangle \, v  \, \mathrm{vol}_{\partial M}- \int_M g( \Delta u, v ) \, \mathrm{vol},
\end{aligned}$$

where $N$ denotes the unit outward normal of $M$.

Usually one has to take certain boundary conditions on $u$ into account. The so-called Dirichlet boundary conditions are easiest to discuss. Suppose we want to minimize $E(u)$ subject to $u|_{\partial M} = u_0$. Then any allowed variation (a so-called infinitesimal displacement) $v$ of $u$ has to satisfy $v_{\partial M} = 0$. That means if $u$ is a minimizer of our optimization problem, then it has to satisfy

$$ 0 = DE(u) \, v = - \int_M g( \Delta u, v ) \, \mathrm{vol} \quad \text{for all smooth $v \colon M \to \mathbb{R}$ with $v_{\partial M} = 0$.}$$

By the [fundamental lemma of calculus of variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_calculus_of_variations), this leads to the Poisson equation

$$ \left\{\begin{array}{rcll}
- \Delta u &= &0, &\text{in the interior of $M$,}\\
u_{\partial M} &= &u_0.
\end{array}\right.$$

Notice that this did not require the choice of any coordinates, making these entities and computations [*covariant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_covariance) in the Einsteinian sense.

This argumentation can also be generalized to more general (vector-valued, tensor-valued, spinor-valued, or whatever-you-like-valued) fields $u$. 
Actually, this can also be generalized to Lorentzian manifolds $(M,g)$ (where the metric $g$ has signature $(\pm , \mp,\dotsc, \mp)$); then $E(u)$ coincides with the *action* of the system, critical points of $E$ correspond to  *dynamic* solutions, and the resulting Laplacian of $g$ coincides with the wave operator (or d'Alembert operator) $\square$.

Comment: Bit late but I think this has knzhou's answer hidden in it: How is the inner product of gradients defined? You're taking the usual inner product on $\mathbb{R}^3$, right? So I can be pedantic and ask: why not take a different inner product? Rotation and translation invariance seems to be still be the answer.

Comment: Well, if you weaken "rotation-invariance" to "isotropy" (rotation-invariance per tangent space) and abandon the translation invariance, I am with you. My point is that a general (pseudo-)Riemannian manifold need not have any global isometries. But the Laplacians/d'Alembert operator is still well-defined.

Answer (score 18):

The expression you've given for the Laplacian, 
$$
\nabla^2=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2},
$$
is a valid way to express it, but it is not a particularly useful definition for that object. Instead, a much more useful way to see the Laplacian is to define it as
$$
\nabla^2 f = \nabla \cdot(\nabla f),
$$
i.e., as the divergence of the gradient, where:

- The **gradient** of a scalar function $f$ is the vector $\nabla f$ which points in the direction of fastest ascent, and whose magnitude is the rate of growth of $f$ in that direction; this vector can be cleanly characterized by requiring that if $\boldsymbol{\gamma}:\mathbb R \to E^3$ is a curve in Euclidean space $E^3$, the rate of change of $f$ along $\boldsymbol\gamma$ be given by
  $$
  \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}f(\boldsymbol{\gamma}(t)) = \frac{\mathrm d\boldsymbol{\gamma}}{\mathrm dt} \cdot \nabla f(\boldsymbol{\gamma}(t)).
  $$
- The **divergence** of a vector field $\mathbf A$ is the scalar $\nabla \cdot \mathbf A$ which characterizes how much $\mathbf A$ 'flows out of' an infinitesimal volume around the point in question. More explicitly, the divergence at a point $\mathbf r$ is defined as the normalized flux out of a ball $B_\epsilon(\mathbf r)$ of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $\mathbf r$, in the limit where $\epsilon \to 0^+$, i.e. as
  $$
  \nabla \cdot \mathbf A(\mathbf r) = \lim_{\epsilon\to0^+} \frac{1}{\mathrm{vol}(B_\epsilon(\mathbf r)} \iint_{\partial B_\epsilon(\mathbf r))} \mathbf A \cdot \mathrm d \mathbf S.
  $$

Note that both of these definitions are completely independent of the coordinate system in use, which also means that they are invariant under translations and under rotations. It just so happens that $\nabla^2$ happens to coincide with $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2},$ but that is a happy coincidence: the Laplacian occurs naturally in multiple places because of its translational and rotational invariance, and that then implies that the form $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}$ happens frequently. But that's just hanging on from the properties of the initial definition.

Comment: It makes sense to me why a gradient defined in that way would be simpler for Cartesian coordinates, since they also form a basis in the strict sense of a vector space, which spherical coordinates don't. In the definition you gave, normalization/units are sneaking in, I think: The dot product implies the units must be the same to be added together. Which is weird because the left-hand side definition, $\frac{d}{dt}f(\gamma(t))$, doesn't seem to use units at all. But: The derivative of $f$ can't be defined without a metric on $E^3$, and the metric sneaks in the necessary normalization.

Comment: An attempted summary of your answer: The Laplacian looks nice with Cartesian coordinates because they play nice with the $L^2$ norm, and we want that because real-life distance uses the $L^2$ norm.